# Iteration for simple linear regression model

Tags: r, loops, data.table, linear-regression, prediction

I would like to fit/train a predictive model and do it intertatively, that is, for example, I train my model every `50` days in the selected period (here: all of 2020). Basically I want to predict the second column (`DE`) and use the remaining columns and parameters for the prediction. My data table can look like this:

```
set.seed(123)
days <- 50
## Create random data table: ##
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                      "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                      "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)
```

The date range of my data table, the number of predictors and the number of days (`days`) can always differ. I have already done the model fitting/training for the whole data table once, but I do not know how to do this iteratively every `50` days? Here you can see a code snippet of my model fitting for a linear model:

```
v.trainDate <- dt.data$date
## Delete column "date" of train data for model fitting: ##
dt.data <- dt.data[, c("date") := NULL]

## MODEL FITTING: ##
## Linear Model: ##
lmModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1, data = dt.data)

## Train PREDICTION with lmModel: ##
dt.data$prediction <- stats::predict.glm(lmModel, dt.data)
## Add date columns to dt.train: ##
dt.data <- data.table(date = v.trainDate, dt.data)
```

What I want to have at the end is that I train the model with my data first from `2020-01-01` to `2020-02-20` (first 50 days) and predict the `DE` price with this fitted model `lmModel` for the first fifty entries of my data table. Next run should be to train my model from `2020-02-20` to `2020-04-10` (next 50 days) and predict the values for this new 50 days. This should be done until the last December day for 2020. At the end I need a column, called`prediction` as you can see in my code snippet, but this column should consist the interatively constructed predictions of the `DE` price.

I would also like to save the Variable Importance somewhere after each iteration? So that I can see which variable had the most influence on the `DE` price in the first 50 days, etc. Does anyone know how this could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `calclm` function below calculates prediction and the `calcImportance` function calculates variable importance.

`by=seq_len(nrow(dt.data)) %/% days` argument using `data.table` splits the dataset in `days` chuncks and applies the previous functions to each chunck :

```r
library(data.table)
library(caret)

## Create random data table: ##
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                      "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                      "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)

set.seed(123)
days <- 50

# Prediction calculation
calcPred <- function(data) {
  lmModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)
  stats::predict.glm(lmModel, data)
}

# Importance calculation
calcImportance <- function(data) {
  lmModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)
  terms <- attr(lmModel$terms , "term.labels")
  varimp <- caret::varImp(lmModel)
  importance <- data[,.(date,imp = t(varimp))]
}

importance.data <- data.table::copy(dt.data)
importance.data[,calcImportance(.SD),by=seq_len(nrow(dt.data)) %/% days]
#>      seq_len       date imp.Wind imp.Solar imp.Nuclear imp.ResLoad
#>   1:       0 2020-01-01 4.598201 2.4726894   0.7993097   1.7153244
#>   2:       0 2020-01-02 4.598201 2.4726894   0.7993097   1.7153244
#>   3:       0 2020-01-03 4.598201 2.4726894   0.7993097   1.7153244
#>   4:       0 2020-01-04 4.598201 2.4726894   0.7993097   1.7153244
#>   5:       0 2020-01-05 4.598201 2.4726894   0.7993097   1.7153244
#>  ---                                                              
#> 362:       7 2020-12-27 1.093177 0.2558265   0.1610440   0.5383146
#> 363:       7 2020-12-28 1.093177 0.2558265   0.1610440   0.5383146
#> 364:       7 2020-12-29 1.093177 0.2558265   0.1610440   0.5383146
#> 365:       7 2020-12-30 1.093177 0.2558265   0.1610440   0.5383146
#> 366:       7 2020-12-31 1.093177 0.2558265   0.1610440   0.5383146

dt.data[,c('prediction'):=calcPred(.SD),by=seq_len(nrow(dt.data)) %/% days]

dt.data
#>            date       DE     Wind      Solar   Nuclear  ResLoad prediction
#>   1: 2020-01-01 36.51972 5000.608  1.4283653  92.19844 200.1163   35.02625
#>   2: 2020-01-02 34.96544 4999.235  0.3860045  92.29005 203.2613   34.96200
#>   3: 2020-01-03 35.16448 5002.232 -1.4450524 100.32920 202.5225   35.67255
#>   4: 2020-01-04 36.07978 5000.564 -0.9137483  98.07459 206.3788   35.13325
#>   5: 2020-01-05 35.10967 4997.606  4.9788029 101.27625 201.8148   34.29788
#>  ---                                                                      
#> 362: 2020-12-27 34.98190 4997.936  2.6117305  98.33027 195.1352   34.80871
#> 363: 2020-12-28 35.16974 4998.799  1.0776123 108.26064 195.2474   35.01232
#> 364: 2020-12-29 35.37956 4998.651  3.9252237 102.87948 201.0266   35.09362
#> 365: 2020-12-30 35.51517 4999.428  5.9747031  92.38721 196.4204   34.60962
#> 366: 2020-12-31 33.53278 5001.911  3.5062344  93.60744 197.5292   34.85689
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to need the variable importance for all existing variables over the time period. I don't really know how to do this, but basically I would like a table with: 1st column ```date``` and the remaining columns are the predictors (ResLoad, Nuclear, ...). I don't know what measure you can take for it? But for example, that in the end I got values between 0 and 1 for each column (each predictor) over the time period, with values close to 1 being very important and values close to 0 less important.

Comment: The prediction works wonderfully and should also be added as a column to the data table, thanks for that.
A table with the importance of the individual predictors would simply be great.

Comment: Ok how can I generalize that without referring directly to the column names? Because as already described above in the question, the predictors are always different and I only gave one example. It can also happen that I have a total of 20 predictors with different names. Or just two.

Comment: The table must therefore be adapted automatically and use the correct column names by itself

Comment: I would prefer to create a separate table for the variable importance with a date column and the remaining columns are the importance of the individual predictors.

Comment: Addtionally, the ```date``` column is not a predictor (it should be deleted before the model fitting or the model training).

Comment: are you sure the formula you used excludes date? what is the result of  `attr(lmModel$terms , "term.labels")`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because before I use the call ```lm()``` I'm deleting the column ```date```with the following code: ```dt.data <- dt.data[, c("date") := NULL]```. The dates are save before in a vector.

Comment: OK, I missed this one. I corrected it another way by setting `-date` in the formula. See my edit.

Comment: Had to copy the data.table to avoid reference pb between the 2 functions

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I don't know the ```varImp()``` function. Are higher values synonymous with important variables and lower values with less important variables?

Comment: That's it, actually its in case of `lm` [the absolute value of the t-statistic](https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html).

Comment: Alright! I'm also trying to do the same with MARS, but it comes to an error for the ```varImp(model, value = "gcv")``` in R: ```Error in as.data.frame.default(x, ...) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"varImp.train"’ to a data.frame ```. I don't understand the error with respect to the data frame, I don't have a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be one way to do it, using the nice features of nested data frames and the `map()` function. Basically create first a dataset of starting dates, then selecting the data relevant for that starting date, then running the regression and extracting the results. The final output is shown as a dataset where rows represent the first date of the sample, and columns the date for which the data is predicted.

```r
library(tidyverse)
days <- 50
set.seed(123)
## Create random data table: ##
data <- tibble(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                  "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                  "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)


data_out <- tibble(train_start_date= tail(data$date, -50)) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(train_start_date, ~filter(data, date >=.x) %>% 
                      head(50)),
         lmModel =map(data, ~stats::lm(DE ~ .-1, data = .x)),
         prediction= map2(lmModel, data,  ~tibble(train_end_date=max(.y$date), 
                                                  prediction=predict(.x), 
                                                 prediction_date = .y$date))) %>% 
  select(train_start_date, prediction) %>% 
  unnest(prediction) %>% 
  mutate(train_n_days = as.integer(train_end_date-train_start_date)+1) %>% 
  select(train_start_date, train_end_date, train_n_days, prediction_date, prediction)

data_out
#> # A tibble: 14,575 x 5
#>    train_start_date train_end_date train_n_days prediction_date prediction
#>    <date>           <date>                <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
#>  1 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-20            35.0
#>  2 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-21            35.0
#>  3 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-22            35.1
#>  4 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-23            35.2
#>  5 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-24            34.6
#>  6 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-25            35.2
#>  7 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-26            35.0
#>  8 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-27            35.0
#>  9 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-28            35.1
#> 10 2020-02-20       2020-04-09               50 2020-02-29            35.1
#> # … with 14,565 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't try your code because it throws the following error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Furthermore, I don't really understand the output of the table. Let's say ```days<-30``` or ```31```, then I want to train my linear model for every month and after training, I want to predict the values for that month. So I train my model with the data from the days of January and predict the values for each day in January, then I train my model with the data from February and predicteach day of February, then I train the model with the data from March and predict the days of March, and so on. Until the end of my data table.

Comment: My preferred output after predicting my dataset would be a single column - called ```prediction```- for all iterations. The first 30 lines of this column ```prediction``` would be my first training of the model. The next 30 lines, for my second model training, etc.

Comment: Hi @Michi, I updated the output as per your request (long format instead of wide, just removing the last `spread` line). Now format is long, you have a single prediction column, another indicating for which the the data is predicted, then you have a column indicating the train start/end dates and size of sample.